# Which dental implants would be better?

Tags: dentistry, implant

My upper left molar (teeth #7) crumbled and the crown also broke down.

The dentist suggested to go for a tooth extraction, followed by an implant.

Is it fine if I avoid the implant, and only do the molar extraction?

If no, then which product is better out of following

- CSM
- Osteon
- Nobel biocare

Which one would be good in my condition?

Comment: You have not really provided enough information.  However, I will warn you that you need either an implant, a spacer, or a  partial bridge. If you do nothing you risk your other teeth drifting out of line.

Comment: Have you googled something like "Are implants really necessary?" or "Under what conditions an implant is necessary?" Please include your own research on your post